# NSTimeZone.systemTimeZone status not determined

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, nstimezone

I've done some digging and I cannot find more information on when system timezone fails.

In our App we're doing some client-side timezone management. For one of our users (at least the one that emailed us), it appears their iPhone cannot determine the system timezone set in their Date & Time preferences, and is returning the default GMT.

According to Apple's documentation:

> The time zone currently used by the system. If the current time zone cannot be determined, returns the GMT time zone.

This user is seeing all of their data as if they were placed in GMT (+0), despite being in EST (-4).

I'm looking for:

1) If there's any way to know that system timezone cannot be determined and is defaulting to GMT?

2) If there are any external reasons for this, i.e. would jail breaking a phone potentially cause this?

3) (edit) Is there another API that might help cross check the validity of system timezone?

For reference, we're calling the localTimeZone() object, without a default timezone set, so this should return the current system timezone, and then return the local cache of that system timezone in subsequent calls.

Comment: Are you using swift or Objective c? Add the relevant tag to your question to help people to help you

Comment: Maybe this user has turned off "set automatically" for their time zone? Usually it updates automatically, but people can disable that. I'd also ask if their phone shows the correct time of day for their time zone.